# Repair charset encoding in a saved UTF-8 document from iso-8859-1

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I need your help.

I have a large UTF-8 JSON document in which some string properties came from an ISO-8859-1 source.

That turns out to produce this example :

```
{
  "id":"3",
  "name_fr":"AlgÃ©rie",
  "name_en":"Algeria"
};

...

{
  "id":"7",
  "label":"Horizon 2020",
  "link":"http://www.rennes-metropole.fr/developpement-durable/horizon-2020/horizon-2020-l-exposition.html",
  "comment":"<P ALIGN=\"LEFT\">LÃ¢â¬â¢exposition ÃÂ« Horizon 2020 ÃÂ» est une promenade dans le Pays de Rennes. Dans cette promenade, vous rencontrez huit Ã©tapes qui concernent les principales questions Ã  l&apos;horizon 2020.</P>",
  "illustration_file_id":"0"
},
```

Is there any easy way to fix my document considering this :

- This document is almost 500 KB large
- I can not just find/replace because it also contains mis-encoded characters like " « " that became " ÃÂ« "

?

I am trying to do this either in php or javascript, but i am open to any solution.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: FYI, "fix" tag is for FIX protocol, not because you need to fix something.

Comment: Can you add some details on what was the original input, what was done to it, and how you are visualizing this output? What you see is what you would expect to see when viewing a UTF-8 document with a program that expected the ISO-8859-1 encoding, so it's not clear if anything is actually wrong with the output.

Comment: The original input comes from FlashFirebug, that I used to get JSON objects from AMF responses. Firefox/Chrome and Firebug were UTF-8, but the server and the responses was ISO-8859-*.
I didn't think about using iconv() at the begining because I thought it would be more complex.
I tried playing with XML charset declarations, other AMF clients (none of them worked) and many other solutions.
Thanks a lot for your support by answering me =)

Answer (score 0):

Found it !

Just converted my JSON document to a PHP file, then wrapped it with :

```
<?php

$string = <<<EOF
MY huge JSON DOCUMENT
EOF;

echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $string);
```

Then ran it under mamp.

Thank you !